# R programming Sum data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, digits

i have a code using R language, i want to sum all data frame (df$number is unlist result in 'res')

total result is = [1]  1  3  5  7  9 20 31 42

```
digits <- function(x){as.integer(substring(x, seq(nchar(x)), seq(nchar(x))))}
generated <- function(x){ x + sum(digits(x))} 
digitadition <- function(x,N) { c(x, replicate(N-1, x <<- generated(x))) } 
res <- NULL
for(i in 0:50){
for(j in 2:50){
tmp <-  digitadition(i,j)
IND <- 50*(i-1) + (j-1) - (i-1) #to index results
res[IND] <- tmp[length(tmp)]
}
} 

df <- data.frame(number = unlist(res), generator=rep(1:50, each=49), N=2:50)

total <- table(df$number)[as.numeric(names(table(df$number)))<=50]

setdiff(1:50,  as.numeric(names(total)))

sum(total)
```

i'm using `sum(total)` but the result of summary is '155' it is not the right answer, cause the right answer is '118'

what the spesific code to sum the 'total'?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and I think you may be confused on what you want to sum.

You `setdiff` contains the values `1  3  5  7  9 20 31 42` which sum is 118.

So, if you do `sum(setdiff(1:50,  as.numeric(names(total))))`, you'll get the 118 you are looking for.

---

Your `total` variable is different from this. Let me explain what you are doing and what I think you should do.

Your code: `total <- table(df$number)[as.numeric(names(table(df$number)))<=50]`]

When you `table()`, you get each unique value from the vector, and the number of how many times this number appears on your vector.

And when you get the `names()` of this table, you get each of these unique values as a `character`, that's why you are setting `as.numeric`.

But the function `unique()` do this job for you, he extracts uniques values from a vector.

Here's what you can do: `total <- unique(df$number[which(df$number <= 50)])`

Where `which()` get the ID's of values <= 50, and unique extracts unique values of these ID's.

And finally: `sum(setdiff(1:50,  total))` that sums all the values from 1 to 50 that are not in your `total` vector.

And in my opinion, `sum(setdiff(total,  1:50))` its more intuitive.

Comment: Thank you TheBiro for the answer especially about your explanation using unique() and which()

Comment: And also remember when you want to update a variable you have to use the `<-` like with setdiff: `total <- setdiff(1:50,  total)`. Executing a function without assign it to a variable is usefull when you just need to print the result on the console.